# curl from a bat file is giving different results than from command line

Tags: batch-file, curl

I have a bat file with the single command.  When I execute it from the build.bat file I get a 6KB file that looks like it's complete with with tons of missing content.

```
curl --data "loc=C%3A%5CUsers%5Cuser1%5CDocuments%5test%5Cengizmo&subdirs=1&verbosity=4&vector=all&treestyle=1&stylesheet=notepad++" -s -o "C:\tmp\curl.html" --url "http://localhost:8001/rips/main.php"
```

When I execute the same line from the command line I get a 65KB file with the expected output.  I've deleted the output file numerous times so I know that each is creating the right files.

curl 7.45.0 (i386-pc-win32) libcurl/7.45.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2a zlib/1.2.8 libssh2/1.4.3

Comment: Can you set echo on and check the actual command executed in batch? Could the percent symbols be stripped?

Comment: When this line is inserted in a Batch file, each percent must be duplicated: `curl --data "loc=C%%3A%%5CUsers%%5Cuser1...`

Comment: Thank you that was the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer as shree.pat18 figured out was I did not use the escape characters for the % file in the data for the curl call.

Comment: actual correct code transcends language and interpretation. Consider updating your answer to show your complete, correct command. Good luck to all.